# Famous businessman mathematical puzzle ${}{}$

Tags: arithmetic, education, puzzle

question:  A Businessman  advertised two job openings for peons in his firm. Two men applied and the businessman decided to engage both of them. He offered them salary of $2000$ rupees per year. $1000$ rupees to be paid every half year,with a promise that their salary would be raised if their work proved satisfactory.They could have a raise of $300$ rupees per year ,(or) if they preferred,$100$ rupees each half year .The two men thought for few moments and then one of them expressed his wish to take the raise at $300$ rupees per year ,while the other man said he would accept the half yearly increase of $100$ rupees .between the two men,who was gainer .

$(a)$ First person

$(b)$ second person

$(c)$ both are equal

$(d)$none of these

**my attempt** :i thought answer should be first person because after one year he will get total sum as $1000+1000+300$(yearly raise)$=2300$

and second person ,after one year,end up getting $1000+100+1000+100=2200 $

so, definitely $300$ yearly offer is more lucrative .

but answer is given option $(b)$

please explain

Comment: Is there a possibility that something such as interest rates are at play? As in, the second person could put his money in the bank and with compound interest rates earn more than the other person who takes 300 rupees a year? Is this a possibility or does the question as you stated it cover all information we are allowed to use?

Comment: question is stated as it is ..without any alteration

Comment: The first person would receive 2000 for the first year, 2300 for second, 2600 for the third, and so on. The second would receive (1000+1100) for the first, (1200+1300) for the second, (1400+1500) for the third, etc.

Comment: Well, you computation for case $b$ is wrong...post the first raise, after six months the man gets $1100$ and after another six months he gets $1200$ for a total of $2300$ for the year (same as in case $a$).

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the interpretation of case $a$. Is the $300$ an annual raise or a semi-annual raise?  In both cases, I think the timing of the pay raises is ambiguous.

Comment: This problem goes back to Dudeney, Amusements in Mathematics, from 1917 (and maybe earlier).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I interpret this problem, the salaries go as follows:

Person 1:

He gets paid $2000$ for the first year, $2300$ for the second year, $2600$ for the third year, etc. So for the $n$th year he gets paid $2000+300(n-1)$.

Person 2:

He gets paid $1000+1100$ for the first year, $1200+1300$ for the second year, $1400+1500$ for the third year, etc. So he does end up getting paid more, year-by-year, because his raises occur more frequently and so can build up more.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose if they get $100$ each half year. Then the following are the possible outcomes
$$1^{st}\mbox{ year }\ \ \ \ \ \  1000+1100=2100$$
$$2^{nd}\mbox{ year }\ \ \ \ \ \  1200+1300=2500$$
$$3^{rd}\mbox{ year }\ \ \ \ \ \  1400+1500=2900$$
$$4^{th}\mbox{ year }\ \ \ \ \ \  1600+1700=3300$$

Suppose if they get $300$ each per year. Then the following are the possible outcomes
$$1^{st}\mbox{ year }\ \ \ \ \ \  1000+1000=2000$$
$$2^{nd}\mbox{ year }\ \ \ \ \ \  1150+1150=2300$$
$$3^{rd}\mbox{ year }\ \ \ \ \ \  1300+1300=2600$$
$$4^{th}\mbox{ year }\ \ \ \ \ \  1450+1450=2900$$

Now can you see which one is profitable.

Answer (score 2):

You are paid at the end of the work period, so in the first year the first man gets $1000$ twice for $2000$, then is raised to $2300/$year for the second year.  The second gets $1000$ for the first six months and $1100$ for the second, giving a total of $2100$.  He is ahead by $100$ after the first year.

The second year the first man gets $1150$ each time for a total of $2300$.  The second gets another raise to $1200$ for the first six months and one to $1300$ for the second six months, giving a total of $2500$.  He is ahead by $200$ in the second year.

In general, in year $k$, the first man gets $2000+300(k-1)$.  The second gets $2000+2\cdot 100\cdot (k-1)+2\cdot 100 \cdot (k-1)+100=2000+400(k-1)+100$ and his advantage grows by $100$ each year.

Answer (score 1):

You have calculated the year end salary of the first person correctly as he's getting his salary annually with an annual raise of $300$. So

$$N_1 = 2000+300=2300/year$$

Now the second person is getting his salary and his raises half yearly

$$N_2 = 1000+100 =1100/half year$$
during the first half. Now during the second half he again gets a raise of $100$ making his salary

$$N_3 = 1100 +100 =1200/halfyearly =2400/year$$

Comment: You are granting the raises too early.  Look at Ross Millikan's answer.

Comment: @saulspatz all these salaries are at the end of the first year, not during

Comment: But the question is not what the salary is, it is how much money you get in your pocket.

Comment: @RossMillikan But this shows that the second person's salary is increasing in an year and therefore he'll end up making more

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other questions assume one person gets a raise starting six months before the other, but it turns out it doesn't matter.

Consider they both work for one year before any raises go into effect: $2000$ and $2000$. The second year, one gets a bonus of $300$ total ($150$ per pay), while the other gets a bonus of $300$ total ($100$ and then $200$ per pay). At the end of the second year, they are still both equal ($2300$ and $2300$ annual pay). The third year they start to diverge.

In the third year, one gets a bonus of $600$ total (increase from $300$ to $600$ total, for $300$ per pay), while the other gets a bonus of $700$ total (increase from $200$ to $300$, and then again from $300$ to $400$). In this way the total sums continue to diverge by $100$ per year.

You can see that eventually the $100$ per pay increase is more beneficial.